# Selecting Networx subgraph views by eliminating subtrees

Tags: networkx

I want to create a subgraph view of a [Networkx](https://networkx.org/) graph. The graph is a tree and in the subgraph view I wish to eliminate all nodes that meet a certain criteria along with their descendants.

For example if my graph is a tree of integers.

```
g = DiGraph()
g.add_edges_from([(1, 5), (1, 7), (1,8), (8, 9), (8, 13), (7,4), (7,19)])
```

I want a subgraph view that eliminates all even nodes and their descendants.

```
subgraph = DiGraph()
subgraph.add_edges_from([(1, 5), (1, 7), (7,19)])
```

I see how to create subgraph views by filtering on [nodes and edges](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/classes/generated/networkx.classes.graphviews.subgraph_view.html), but I don't see how to use this for what I want. A graph traversal algorithm with early exit would do thw trick, but I don't see this functionality in Networkx.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

There are [several DAG traversal options in networkx](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/traversal.html), here is one option:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import networkx as nx

g = nx.DiGraph([(1, 5), (1, 7), (1, 8), (8, 9), (8, 13), (7, 4), (7, 19)])

remove = set()
for node in g:
    if not (node % 2) & (node not in remove):
        successors = nx.dfs_preorder_nodes(g, node)
        remove |= set(successors)

h = nx.subgraph(g, [node for node in g if node not in remove])

print(h.nodes)
# [1, 5, 7, 19]

print(remove)
# {4, 8, 9, 13}
```